# How to color the plot background depending on time of day

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have the following data:

```py
import random
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

random.seed(0)

df = pd.DataFrame({'DATE_TIME': pd.date_range('2022-11-01', '2022-11-06 23:00:00', freq='20min'),
                   'ID': [random.randrange(1, 3) for n in range(430)]})
df['VALUE1'] = [random.uniform(110, 160) for n in range(430)]
df['VALUE2'] = [random.uniform(50, 80) for n in range(430)]
df['INSPECTION'] = df['DATE_TIME'].dt.day

df['MODE'] = np.select([df['INSPECTION'] == 1, df['INSPECTION'].isin([2, 3])], ['A', 'B'], 'C')
df['TIME'] = df['DATE_TIME'].dt.time
df['TIME'] = df['TIME'].astype('str')

df['TIMEINTERVAL'] = df.DATE_TIME.diff().astype('timedelta64[m]')
df['TIMEINTERVAL'] = df['TIMEINTERVAL'].fillna(0)

def to_day_period(s):
    bins = ['0', '06:00:00', '13:00:00', '18:00:00', '23:00:00', '24:00:00']
    labels = ['Nighttime', 'Daytime', 'Daytime', 'Nighttime', 'Nighttime']
    return pd.cut(
        pd.to_timedelta(s),
        bins=list(map(pd.Timedelta, bins)),
        labels=labels, right=False, ordered=False
    )

df['TIME_OF_DAY'] = to_day_period(df['TIME'])
df_monthly = df

df_1 = df[(df.ID==1) & (df.INSPECTION==1)]

def customize_ts(df=df_1):
    order = np.lexsort([df_1['DATE_TIME'].sub(pd.Timedelta('12h')).dt.time,
                        df_1['DATE_TIME'].dt.normalize()])

    out = df_1.iloc[order]
    return out

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

df_customized = customize_ts(df=df_1)
sns.lineplot(data=df_customized, x='TIME', y='VALUE1', ax=ax,color='red')
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(5))

df_customized.reset_index(inplace=True)

for i, row in df_customized.iterrows():
    if row['TIME_OF_DAY'] == 'Daytime':
        ax.axvspan(i-0.5, i+0.5, color='lightblue', alpha=0.5)
        ax.text((i-0.5+i+0.5)/2, 1.03, 'Day', transform=ax.transAxes,
                fontsize=12, fontweight='bold', va='center', ha='center')
    elif row['TIME_OF_DAY'] == 'Nighttime':
        ax.axvspan(i-0.5, i+0.5, color='darkblue', alpha=0.5)
        ax.text((i-0.5+i+0.5)/2, 1.03, 'Night', transform=ax.transAxes,
                fontsize=12, fontweight='bold', va='center', ha='center')

ax.text(0.5, 1.1, 'Night', transform=ax.transAxes,
        fontsize=14, fontweight='bold', va='top', ha='center')

plt.show()
```

So far, this is what I got with my implementation:

[image]

My implementation somehow shifts x-axis to left sides and created unrelated color on the plot.
i WOULD LIKE TO ADD ON TOP WHETHER IT IS day or Night. Then if it is Night, I want to dark transparent box for night time span. As you can see in my synthetic data, night time is between 18:00:00 and 06:00:00.
This is what I expect:

[image]

How can I achieve this?

**EDIT** Thanks to @Redox I have improved my code. Now I implemented the Night and Day texts, but they do not match what I expect. I expect that Day and Night texts are at the center of each background color and if possible insides the background color. I updated my code accordingly. Here is the output I get from my updated code.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the `df_customized`, you will notice that the index is not increasing from 0 to 35 as you moved the rows back and forth. So, `i` is not increasing sequentially. You need to reset the index before plotting.

Also, `axvspan` has a small border. So, plotting all the strips next to each other will show those lines. So, add `lw=0` to prevent that. In my case, reduced the `..MultipleLocator()` from 20 to 5 as well.

To add the text, as we have several small axvspans, we cant add it to that. So, I have manually added the text using `ax.text()` function. The y-axis goes up to 160, so I have kept the text start at 158. Also, the x-axis goes from 0 to 35, so have used the numbers as below. See if this works.

Updated code below. Hope this is what you are looking for...

```
  :
  :
sns.lineplot(data=df_customized, x='TIME', y='VALUE1', ax=ax)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(5)) ## Reduced locators to 5

## Add this line...
df_customized.reset_index(inplace=True)

for i, row in df_customized.iterrows():
    if row['TIME_OF_DAY'] == 'Daytime':
        ax.axvspan(i-0.5, i+0.5, color='lightblue', alpha=0.5, lw=0) ## Add lw
    elif row['TIME_OF_DAY'] == 'Nighttime':
        ax.axvspan(i-0.5, i+0.5, color='darkblue', alpha=0.5, lw=0) ## Add lw

#adding text inside the plot
ax.text(4, 158, 'DAY', fontsize = 12)     ## First DAY
ax.text(18, 158, 'NIGHT', fontsize = 12)  ## NIGHT
ax.text(31, 158, 'DAY', fontsize = 12)    ## Second DAY
    
plt.show()
```

[image]